# show Image database in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-viewflipper

i have to button : first button is for save image from gallery to database , second button is for show images from database in viewFlipper but second button dont work and have error

first button :

```
public void save(View view)
{
        if(bitmap != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
            byte[] byteImage = stream.toByteArray();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(imageColumnName, String.valueOf(byteImage));

            db.insert(tableName, null, values);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Save Image First!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


 }
```

second button :

```
public void showImage(View view)
{
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(2500);
    viewFlipper.startFlipping();

    cursor = db.rawQuery(Query_Select_All ,  null);
    int i = 1;
    if(cursor.getCount() != 0)
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("select image from imageColumns where id = "+i , null);
            String path = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(imageColumnName));
            File imageFile = new File(path);
            Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.toString());
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
            viewFlipper.addView(imageView);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

logcat error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick   
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the stack trace from the log.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Index -1** is caused by `getColumnIndex` not finding the column name in the table in this line `String path = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(imageColumnName));`

That is `imageColumnName` does not resolve to `image`, the column that is selected by the query that extracts the cursor, as per `select`**`image`**`..`

You could perhaps change :-

```
    Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("select image from imageColumns where id = "+i , null);
```

to

```
    Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("select " + imageColumnName + " from imageColumns where id = "+i , null); // The cursor includes just the one column
```

or to

```
    Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("select * from imageColumns where id = "+i , null); // The cursor includes all columns (most flexible)
```

As such the following would likely work :-

```
public void showImage(View view)
{
    ViewFlipper viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
    viewFlipper.setFlipInterval(2500);
    viewFlipper.startFlipping();

    cursor = db.rawQuery(Query_Select_All ,  null);
    int i = 1;
    if(cursor.getCount() != 0)
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery("select * from imageColumns where id = "+i , null);
            String path = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(imageColumnName));
            File imageFile = new File(path);
            Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.toString());
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImage);
            viewFlipper.addView(imageView);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

### Notes

- The use of perhaps and likely is because the actual names of the columns are not clear from the supplied code.

> I and perhaps many others, would recommend creating constants in the respective class for table
> names, columns and database names and always using those rather than
> hard coding such names throughout the code, so that there is just the
> one definition. Doing such can reduce/eliminate such easily made
> errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my problem is still unresolved , my columns name is image but i changed image to imageColumnsName in rawQuery But there is still problem

Comment: Finally, I found the problem , I used two Cursors and The problem was here